# is it normal that number of cancellable items is getting higher?

Tags: swift, mvvm, combine

I have a SwiftUI login-view with 2 textfields for username, password and a login button. I am using MVVM design pattern, and want my viewModel to authenticate after the user clicks on Login-Button.

the implementation of the view is as following

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            TextField("Enter e-mail address", text: $viewModel.email)
            TextField("Enter password", text: $viewModel.password)
            
            Button("Login") {
                viewModel.login()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the viewModel

```swift
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    
    var authenticate = PassthroughSubject<User, Never>()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        authenticate.sink { user in
            Webservice().authenticate(username: user.username, passsword: user.password).sink { error in
                //
            } receiveValue: { token in
                //
            }.store(in: &self.cancellables)
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func login() {
        authenticate.send(User(username: email, password: password))
    }
}
```

everything works fine, but the number of items in cancellables increases everytime the user clicks the login button. I suppose this shouldn't be like that. what's wrong here?

Comment: If the answer addressed your question - which seems to be the case from the code in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689833/subscription-cancels-when-receivecompletion-with-error) - then please mark the answer as accept to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you click login:

1. you send a new user event in `authenticate`
2. In sink of `authenticate`, a brand-new request is created and stored to cancellables.

That second point is where cancellables are increasing, which are may be already `completed` after getting response but will be cleaned up with the deallocation of cancellables. That is normal.

But what may be not normal is, when you are requesting a new login attempt you better cancel your previous login attempt (if not already completed). If you want to do that, keep that cancellable from webservice separate and cancel previous instance before trying new.

```swift
private var loginCancellable: AnyCancellable?

// ... in init
authenticate.sink { user in
    loginCancellable.cancell()
    loginCancellable = Webservice().authenticate(username: user.username, passsword: user.password).sink { error in
        //
    } receiveValue: { token in
        //
    }
// ... rest of the code
```

**NOTE:** Writing all this code just from top of my head. Not tested. You might need to tweak it a bit. But hope you get the idea.

**UPDATE:** [New Dev's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664174/1092078) is what you should go for. `FlatMapLatest` in *RxSwift* is essentially expressed as `map { .. }.switchToLatest()` in *Combine*. And as a general idea, always thrive for a chaining solution instead of closure when working in reactive manner. My approach above can just give you an idea, what you were missing conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

The number of subscriptions shouldn't increase with each emitted value. The reason it does increase in your case is because you have a `sink` within a `sink` - the inner `sink` cancellable is added to the set for every `authenticate.send()` emitted value.

But this nested `sink` isn't the right way to approach this. Instead, you should create a pipeline by chaining `authenticate` that emits a `User` value with something that creates a new publisher that actually does that job of "transforming" `User` (by making the login web request) to a token.

You can typically do this kind of chaining with a `flatMap`, but in your case you'd want to cancel the previous request so you should use a combination of `map`, then `switchToLatest`:

```swift
authenticate
   .map { user in 
      Webservice().authenticate(username: user.username, password: user.password)
   }
   .switchToLatest()
   .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
      //
   }, receiveValue: { token in 
      //
   })
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```

This is a single subscription that starts with `authenticate.send` and gets a token as a value at the end.